# I cant use a lazy var with EnvironmentObject property in a struct

Tags: swiftui, swift5

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coreServices: CoreServices
    
    @State lazy var watchConnectivityService: WatchConnectivityService = {
        coreServices.service(byType: WatchConnectivityService.self)!
    }()
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button("Send Message") {
                watchConnectivityService.session.sendMessage(["message" : self.messageText], replyHandler: nil) { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I write a code like this im noticing that the `@EnvironmentObject` is not available after the initialization is completed. So I cant just use a `@State` variable it needs to be `lazy`...but If I use a `lazy` variable i get *Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `lazy` in SwiftUI view. Use instead function for this case:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coreServices: CoreServices
    
    private func watchConnectivityService() -> WatchConnectivityService {
        coreServices.service(byType: WatchConnectivityService.self)!
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button("Send Message") {
                watchConnectivityService().session.sendMessage(["message" : self.messageText], replyHandler: nil) { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```